# Using Ruby's Logger to have errors go to standard error, but other messages to file/stdout?

Tags: ruby, logging, command-line

I'd like to use Ruby's logger in command-line apps; it beats `puts` and has good flexibility for logging things.

One thing that I would like is to be able to have error/fatal messages go to the standard error (as is customary) *in addition* to where the logger's messages are configured to go.

```
logger = Logger.new(some_file)

logger.debug("This goes to some_file, if debug is set")
logger.info("This goes to some_file, if info is set")
logger.error("This goes to some_file, AND stderr")
```

One way I've done this is to hack the `formatter`:

```
logger.formatter = Proc.new do |severity,time,progname,msg|
  message = format_message(severity,time,progname,msg)
  if severity == ERROR
    $stderr.puts message
  end
  message
end
```

This seems hacky.  Another way might be to create a `Logger` that proxies its calls to an underlying *real* logger, but intercepting the error messages.

Anyone done this, and is there maybe something already that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Anyone done this, and is there maybe something already that does this?

Ruby is cool, and flexible, and powerful, and stuff.  Just with these monkey-patching things and abilities to open a class and add methods, it's too easy to forget about plain old inheritance...

```
class CopyLogger < Logger
  def error message
    # Print to standard error...
    $stderr.puts message
    # ...*and* to wherever you specified as well
    super message
  end
end

logger = CopyLogger.new(some_file)
# ...
```

You may put additional parameters into the constructor of your new class, such as the desired severity to tee messages of, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I usually `tail` the log file to monitor while developing and `put` custom, user friendly messages for the masses.